# Комментирование в phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии `Ctrl + /` комментировался код. Сейчас при нажатии этих клавиш сворачивается блок. В настройках прописаны такие комбинации клавиш: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Как настроить комментирование?

Переключение раскладки не помогло.

Comment: возможно у вас на 2 команды одинаковые горячие клавиши => работает криво. Попробуйте найти горячие клавиши для сворачивания блока и назначить другие

Comment: раскладку переключите и будет коммент а не сворачивание блока

Comment: Переключение раскладки не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так попробуйте. Мне это помогло.